# Networkx - use multiple adjacent matrices to calculate node degree on a volume

Tags: python, networkx, adjacency-matrix

I have 4 adjacent matrices obtained here [link to matrices](https://cosmosimfrazza.myfreesites.net/cosmic-web-and-brain-network-datasets), which represent a distribution of dark matter, ordinary matter and magnetic fields at the present epoch, for a representative cosmic volume of `100^3 Mpc^3`

```
from astropy.io import fits
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
```

If I understood correctly the concept, every file has a `dx=25 Mpc`, which accounts for the total of `100Mpc`.

```
with fits.open('matrix_DMX_A_large_2.fits') as data:
    matrix_dark_matter_a = pd.DataFrame(data[0].data.byteswap().newbyteorder())
    
with fits.open('matrix_DMX_B_large_2.fits') as data:
    matrix_dark_matter_b = pd.DataFrame(data[0].data.byteswap().newbyteorder())
    
with fits.open('matrix_DMX_C_large_2.fits') as data:
    matrix_dark_matter_c = pd.DataFrame(data[0].data.byteswap().newbyteorder())
    
with fits.open('matrix_DMX_D_large_2.fits') as data:
    matrix_dark_matter_d = pd.DataFrame(data[0].data.byteswap().newbyteorder())
```

---

I know how to calculate each 2D network connectivity with a library like `networkx`, simply applying a `sum()` to each matrix row or column, like so:

```
matrix_dark_matter_a['k'] = matrix_dark_matter_a.sum(axis=1)
```

---

How can I build one single adjacent matrix from all matrices, in order to account for all connectivity and apply `networkx` methods -like centrality clustering coefficient etc?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the problem, but what's wrong with summing each matrix individually and then adding the resulting degree distributions per matrix? (subtracting self-connections, if that's present in multiple networks)

Comment: No problem at all. If that’s your answer could you please put it to code?

Comment: Join them together and then do the same computation. https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.all.compose_all.html#networkx.algorithms.operators.all.compose_all